# What does "constituted" mean in this quote from Les Mis by Victor Hugo?

Tags: meaning-in-context

"We are reassured almost as foolishly as we are alarmed; human nature is so constituted."

What does "constituted" mean in this sentence? When I looked it up it said it could mean: "to compose; form", "to appoint to an office or function; make or create", "to establish (laws, an institution, etc.)", "to give legal form to (an assembly, court, etc.)" or "to create or be tantamount to" (["constitute", dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/self-constituting)).

Comment: When I looked it up it said it could mean: to compose; form, to appoint to an office or function; make or create, to establish (laws, an institution, etc.), to give legal form to (an assembly, court, etc.) or to create or be tantamount to,

Comment: And none of those fit??

Comment: Why don't any of those fit? I think one of them fits rather well, but I'm a native speaker, so I don't know what your thinking process is when you read these possible definitions. But native speakers might differ to some degree. We usually don't have a dictionary in our heads just a lifetime of reading... For those who still read.

Comment: You mean, of course, an English translation of Hugo's novel. What's wrong with the first definition?

Comment: "...human nature is, in this manner, created."

Answer (score 1):

> "We are reassured almost as foolishly as we are alarmed; human nature
>   is so constituted."

The difficulty you have here, is that constituted is being used in a non physical sense which is likely what is confusing you.

You can form or create non physical things, such as ideas, beliefs, and feelings, just as you can form or create a physical thing.

What is [human nature](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/human_nature)?

> The general psychological characteristics, feelings, and behavioural
>   traits of humankind, regarded as shared by all humans. - OLD.

You could rewrite your sentence like so:

> We are reassured almost as foolishly as we are alarmed; this is due to
>   the make up of human nature.

Answer (score 1):

Gary answered this question most effectively. For additional information, the original French sentence is :

> "On se rassure presque aussi follement qu’on s’inquiète ; la nature humaine est ainsi."

Which, if translated as directly as possible, would be :

> "We are reassured almost as foolishly as we are alarmed; so is human nature / this is human nature"

The word 'constituted' - or its French equivalent - was therefore not *in* the original text, and was probably added for clarity.